# csvcut: error: unrecognized arguments: filename.csv

Tags: shell, csvkit

Trying to reorder columns in a csv.

This works (calling single column names):

```sh
$ csvcut -c "Node ID" amazon_categories_nodes.csv
```

and this works (calling multiple column indexes):

```sh
$ csvcut -c 4,1,3,5 amazon_categories_nodes.csv
```

But this doesn't work (calling multiple column names):

```sh
$ csvcut -c "Node ID", "Node Path" amazon_categories_nodes.csv
```

```sh
usage: csvcut [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
              [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z FIELD_SIZE_LIMIT] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-H]
              [-K SKIP_LINES] [-v] [-l] [--zero] [-V] [-n] [-c COLUMNS]
              [-C NOT_COLUMNS] [-x]
              [FILE]
csvcut: error: unrecognized arguments: amazon_categories_nodes.csv
```

Tried different combination of column names, also tried 3 or more column names but still receiving the above error message and not sure why? I expect the output to show the same csv but ordered in the way I've specified after `-c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` flag of `csvcut` accepts a comma separated column names or indices ranges to be extracted. Your provided the column names right, but incorrectly included a space after the
`,` as

```
csvcut -c "Node ID", "Node Path" amazon_categories_nodes.csv
#                  ^^^ (incorrect)
```

Since the shell processes the command line arguments before passing it to the appropriate program, it interprets the argument value to `-c` as `"Node ID",` which is incorrect because a un-terminated sequence of comma separated values. Also it ends up leaving the `"Node Path"` value without any argument flags which `csvcut` doesn't understand.

The right solution would be to not leave any space between

```
csvcut -c "Node ID","Node Path" amazon_categories_nodes.csv
```